# C# SendMessage click button

Tags: c#, winapi, user32

Im trying to understand the `SendMessage` function and here's my actual code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process test = Process.GetProcessesByName("calc")[0];
    IntPtr hwndChild = FindWindowEx(test.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "2");
    SendMessage(hwndChild, 245, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Very simple, I just want to click the calc button 2, but I'm having no success.

Comment: Why don't you use automation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error checking is never optional when you pinvoke winapi functions.  It is a C api, it doesn't throw exceptions to keep you out of trouble.  You'll have to do that by yourself.  Proper code looks like this:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, 
                                              string className, string windowTitle);

    ...
    IntPtr hwndChild = FindWindowEx(test.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "2");
    if (hwndChild == IntPtr.Zero) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
```

Now you *know* why your program doesn't work.  Next thing you'd do is fire up the Spy++ utility and have a look-see at the calculator window.  You'll discover that you have to make more FindWindowEx() calls to drill down to the nested button.

Do consider using a UI Automation library to do this.